# 7zip ISO extraction

Tags: iso, 7zip, winrar

I have been trying to extract an ISO image through 7zip and WinRar.

Here is the command line that I used:

```
7z x -y "%Isocontents%\ISO.iso" -o%Newfolder%

WinRar.exe x -y -ow "%Isocontents%\ISO.iso" "%Newfolder%"
```

Entire project uses generic batch / 4NT scripting commands. The above commandline works perfectly when used locally but when run on the actual machine extraction is pretty partial.

This is really strange and I have no clue on what the reason could be.

While extracting it just says like there are only 2 files

```
readme.txt
bootable_noemulation.img
```

I am totally frustrated as this is totally not going per the logic.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue and it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Hey, yes, I did. Please try using the latest version of 7z. That helped resolved my issue.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to extract the files from an `ISO` to a directory then 7zip can do this:

```
7z x -y -oC:\OutputDirectory X:\VRMPVOL_EN.iso
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using the same ISO file, it's possible that the other file is in UDF format.
Check the readme.txt file which might have a note indicating such.

For 7z use the `-t` switch like this `7z x -tudf -y "%Isocontents%\ISO.iso" -o%Newfolder%`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone using MacOS with this question, you can run this command to extract ISO's:

```
7zz x -tiso -y alpine-standard-3.15.0-aarch64.iso -oNewfolder
```

(used an Alpine ISO)